# Equivalent of app.config for a dll COM component

Tags: .net, com, registry, configuration-files

In the .Net world, there is a standard place to store configuration values that can be changed based on the environment you are deploying. That is the app.config/web.config.

Lately I'm having to interop with some legacy COM components.
I understand that COM components are registered in the registry. However, where does one COM component store its application specific settings.

For example, where would the url of a remote service be stored? Is there a standard place like in .Net?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A COM component, in general, is a component and not an application, so it wouldn't make sense to have an specific settings. These belong to the client application.

Typically, COM component is configured by the client app via interfaces provided by the component. Nothing stops the component developer from implementing some custom mechanism (reading from config file), but COM as a technology doesn't provide this functionality out of the box so, in short, there is no COM equivalent to app.config file in .NET. This is similar to how .NET components usually have no config files: you need to configure them through their properties and methods.

OTOH, a COM server can be an .exe (with exposed COM interfaces). In that case, it is again up to the developer of the server to provide config as for any other executable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

As far as my issue is concerned, I had to open Component Services, expand DCOM Config node, right click on the GUID corresponding to the COM component (can be found by using "Go To Definition" in visual studio on the COM interop class), then go to properties, open the location tab and enter the ip address of the remote service.

I think that it is specific to DCOM but that wasn't obvious to find out!